# how to grep exact match?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a CSV file that is delimited by comma. I want to select by the second column that has the exact `"stringPattern"`

I tried:

```
grep -w "stringPattern"
```

but it still gets any string that contains the string Pattern.

What's the awk way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$2=="stringPattern"' FS=,
```

Note that this is an exact match, not a regex.  If you want a regex, you can do:

```
$2 ~ /stringPattern/
```

Comment: You should use `-F,` before the command, it's more portable than `FS=,`

Comment: FS=, is standard awk and worked long before -F,  I question the claim that -F is more portable, and will argue that FS=, is more portable.

Comment: My claim that FS=, "worked long before -F," is incorrect.  Both are mentioned in Aho, Hernighan, and Weinberger's book with no discussion of which appeared first, so they were probably both available in the 1979 version.  They behave slightly differently, with FS=, assignments being more flexible when given multiple input files.  Which to use is personal preference.  (-F assigns before BEGIN, FS= assigns after BEGIN)

Comment: Testing now, it appears FS=, works on BSD awk. I could swear it didn't last time I tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, '$2 == "stringPattern" < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but there is an additional option to **grep** that could be helpful... :-)

From the **grep** manpage:

> ```
> -o, --only-matching
>           Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
> ```

Lets make a small sample file;

```
$ echo -e "col1,col2,col3\npattern1,pattern2,pattern3" > file.csv
```

Now lets search for the pattern, with only the **-w** option

```
$ grep --color=always -w "pattern2" file.csv
pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
```

Now lets search for the pattern with the **-w** and the **-o**

```
$ grep --color=always -ow "pattern2" file.csv
pattern2
```

Now only the *exact* match is returned. :-)

...but what if the pattern "repeats" on the same line?

Lets update the sample file and repeat the last search;

```
$ echo -e "col1,col2,col3,col4\npattern1,pattern2,pattern3,pattern2" > file.csv
```

Now the search returns both results - but on a separate line

```
$ grep --color=always -ow "pattern2" file.csv
pattern2
pattern2
```

This may **not** be what you want. :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^[^,]+,stringPattern,' file
```